# Enum for handling network request errors in Swift

Tags: error-handling, swift, generics, networking, enum

I'm working on a new API written in Swift 5 and I wanted to play with the new `Result`. I wanted to know what you guys think about this syntax:

```swift
enum NetworkRequestError: Error {
    case hostNotAvailable
    case accountNotAvailable

    func finish<T>() -> Result<T, NetworkRequestError> {
        return .failure(self)
    }
}

public class NetworkClient: TestableAPI {
    var host: String?

    func fetch(result: @escaping (Result<(any: [Any], any1: [Any]), NetworkRequestError>) -> Void) {
        guard host != nil else {
            result(NetworkRequestError.hostNotAvailable.finish())
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend this pattern. I see no compelling reason to encumber `NetworkRequestError` (and presumably every other `Error` enumeration throughout your project) with this `finish` cruft.

So, instead of:

```
enum NetworkRequestError: Error {
    case hostNotAvailable
    case accountNotAvailable

    func finish<T>() -> Result<T, NetworkRequestError> {
        return .failure(self)
    }
}

func fetch(result: @escaping (Result<(any: [Any], any1: [Any]), NetworkRequestError>) -> Void) {
    guard host != nil else {
        result(NetworkRequestError.hostNotAvailable.finish())
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

I’d instead suggest:

```
enum NetworkRequestError: Error {
    case hostNotAvailable
    case accountNotAvailable
}

func fetch(result: @escaping (Result<(any: [Any], any1: [Any]), NetworkRequestError>) -> Void) {
    guard let host = host else {
        result(.failure(.hostNotAvailable))
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

This is more concise, conforms to established patterns (making it easier to reason about) and it doesn’t entangle `Error` types and `Result` types.

Also you’re undoubtedly checking `host` because you’re going to use it later in this method, so you might as well do `guard let`, like above. It saves you from having to do subsequent unwrapping of the optional.

---

I’m assuming your question was primarily about the `Error` type and this `finish` method. I must say that I am equally uneasy about the `.success` associated type, namely the tuple of `[Any]` arrays. Perhaps this was just a placeholder in your example, but I generally find references to `Any` to be code smell. Often specific types or generics would be better than `Any` to types in one’s code. If you have a question about why you’re using a “success” type which is two arrays of `Any`, that might warrant its own question, showing why you did that. It, too, could probably be improved.

Comment: Thanks for you clear and detailed answer Rob ! I will follow what you suggest, that was my primary implementation of the result block but I'm using it 3 times in the function so I was wondering if I could shorten my guard statements.But this `it doesn’t entangle Error types and Result types` made it. For the [Any] part, I am not using them in real life, I'm using real objects, but thanks for your concern !